# finding the video and audio access units in MP4 without any headers?

Tags: matlab, video, mp4, h.264

I am trying to find the units in a MP4 file which encoded by H.264. according to specifications of ISO/IEC 14496-12 and ISO/IEC 14496-15 the data (video and audio samples) that stored in mdat are encapsulated in ISO/IEC 14496-15 section 5.2.3 format.

according to [MP4 / ISO 14496-12 : How do you find the video and audio access units?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8525824/mp4-iso-14496-12-how-do-you-find-the-video-and-audio-access-units)

we can find the SPS,PPS and unit size information (NALs are starting  with length of the following NAL unit)in the 'avcC' box.

My question is i have a MP4 video on my computer, i will remove all headers and footers manually (so i dont have any 'avcC' box), how can i find these NAL units?

Comment: Give link to a small example file. You need the SPS and PPS to config the MPEG decoder (_ie:_ what's the resolution? what's the framerate? etc).

Comment: Since i'm working in matlab, i have removed the headers of video and splitted it into 100 fragment and formatted it in 128 KB size, here is the link of one of fragments saved in .mat [link](https://ufile.io/36kcd)

Comment: I should mention that i dont want to config the MPEG decoder, i just want to determine this is a MP4 video.

Comment: PS: I don't use Matlab. Given an MP4 file (without headers) I would suggest checking the bytes for a guess. It depends if the MDAT section presents at first the bytes as data of audio or video. For Video... the first four bytes are slice-A "**size**" so they usually begin with byte 0x00 and it looks like `00 00 xx xx` or even `00 xx xx xx` where `xx` are hex digits. if you skip the bytes amount by given "size" you should find the start of slice-B which too has a 4-byte size. Usually 2 slices make a single picture frame. If MDAT started with byte `21` or similar number it may be MPEG audio

Comment: @VC.how can i find where does the Mdat start? i can't say whenever i see those patterns for video or audio the mdat is started from that point?

Comment: If there are no headers then you are left with nothing but the raw MDAT. Now it's just to find out if the beginning bytes mean video sample or audio sample so you **first test** for audio by checking if first byte is `20` or `21` (if expecting 44,100 hz sound at 16-bit with Stereo). Now if `potential_AAC_frame == false` then check for possible MP3 audio where starting two bytes wuld be `FF FB`... If both tests (AAC & MP3) are false then assume it's potential MPEG video so test that by checking if the starting four bytes give `[ 00 x1 x2 x3]` (`x1` could be `00`) and next byte (fifth) is `[65]`

Comment: PS: I suggest opening your header less mp4 in a freeware hex editor so it's easier to see the bytes at once. Also you should just show here (paste the first 16 or 32 bytes) of such a problem video file for specific advice.

Comment: @VC.One So, i should check these in first bytes of the raw mdat. since i'm working with matlab i remove 1/8 from first and end of the file so i'm not sure if i remove first bytes of mdat with header or not. is there any program so i can just remove headers of file to check the first bytes of mdat?(and be sure that i just remove header)

Comment: There are two links here, one from a short MP4 video and the second one from a middle part of video. first one has the (00 00 x1 x2)[65] pattern but the second one is different.[link](https://ibb.co/e2H0fF), [link](https://ibb.co/ipNSSv).